# How to disable notifications using ChromeOptions through Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to block Chrome notifications when testing using Selenium Webdriver. I have tried using Java commands documented elsewhere on the site, but my additional code is marked as an error each time I try to add it.

```js
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

/**
 * @author Me
 */
public class MyTest {
    static WebDriver webDriver;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Telling the system where to find the chrome driver
        System.setProperty(
                "webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:/Users/Me/Documents/WebDriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

        // Open the Chrome browser
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```

I am trying to add the following commands to my code, but they don't work:

```js
ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
  ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
```

Can anyone tell me where I need to add them into my code snippet? I have tried inserting them above System.setProperty but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To add the *argument* **`--disable-notifications`** you need to initialize an instance of *ChromeOptions* and pass the instance while initializing the *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome Browser* instances as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

/**
 * @author Me
 */
public class MyTest {
    static WebDriver webDriver;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Telling the system where to find the chrome driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/Me/Documents/WebDriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
        ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        ops.addArguments("start-maximized");
        // Open the Chrome browser
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
```

> **Note**: Instead of using `webDriver.manage().window().maximize()`, use the *ChromeOptions* object.